# In browser proxy software

Tags: proxy

We are looking for some software that will help replicate systems like: http://hidemyass.com/ and other less good looking sites if you google "in browser proxy"

What we are trying to do is set a user a task, tell them to visit google.com and start searching for information to complete the task. We would tell them not to use their address bar and use "our" one which would be a simple form passing the url to proxy. We would like to monitor the urls they visit while completing the task.

We are happy to install anything server side in any language and are willing to pay. We've seen web based app solutions, which might be an option, but we would prefer to keep it on our own hardware.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! As stated [in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this is a site for "a specific programming problem; a software algorithm ; software tools commonly used by programmers ; matters that are unique to the programming profession". You seem to be asking for a shopping recommendation; that is not particularly relevant to this site.

Comment: Urm, I'm an active user of StackOverflow. and I have seen questions like this often. It would go under this rule in my opinion. "software tools commonly used by programmers"

Comment: I see *closed* questions like this, often. You seem to be contradicting yourself: "there will be lots of different users who we have no control over" - don't tell me they would all be programmers.

Comment: Yes but its the software we will be using and programming with. I don't expect this to be an off the shelf solution. I expect to have to bodge it. Something like this, which only other programmers would know about. http://code.google.com/p/mirrorrr/

Comment: OK, now I see your point. That project looks like what you're looking for. You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Perls [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.24/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm), it has many [examples](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BOOK/HTTP-Proxy-0.24/eg/).

Comment: @johnwards our users browsers are configured to use this proxy, or you wrap an interface around it (say a webpage allowing users to input a URL) and call it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an existing [proxy script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpproxy/) and modify it or install an existing proxy software, configure the browser to use the proxy and check the logs (you may ask which proxy software is suited on server fault).

Comment: I can't configure the browsers as there will be lots of different users who we have no control over.